# java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT slave failed to start. Please make sure the current build tools are not corrupted

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am learning ionic and for that I have installed the ionic and created a project. But, when I tried to run the project using `ionic cordova run android` command, It gave me following errors.

> AAPT err(Facade for 12682754): *sdk-path*/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: 1: *sdk-path*/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>
> AAPT err(Facade for 30547323): *sdk-path*/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: 1: /home/seven-bits-pc11/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>
> Slave 30547323 failed to start
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT slave failed to start. Please make sure the current build tools (located at *sdk-path*/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2) are not corrupted.
>
> at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:211)
>
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
>
> at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Slave 12682754 failed to start
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT slave failed to start. Please make sure the current build tools (located at /home/seven-bits-pc11/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2) are not corrupted.
>
> at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:211)
>
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
>
> at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.
>   :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

I followed one of the answer in this link https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1256 where they suggested to change  buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion to buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

but, I dont know how and where should i change?

Do anyone have any idea? 
or any other solution for this error? please help me!

Comment: Try to go to Build - Rebuild project. I didn't get that problem again and my app successfully started.

Comment: @HemantParmar how to rebuild project in ionic? as I am new to ionic and i dont know anything much about it. can you please help me?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Ivaro18 yes I found the solution

Comment: @Riddhi do you still know the solution? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @Ivaro18 To be honest, I don't remember the solution. But Due to some problem I had to format my PC and after that I had installed everything again and after that I am not facing this issue. Sorry :(

Comment: @Ivaro18 but, did you try to rebuild?

Comment: How do I rebuild with ionic? ._.

Comment: @Ivaro18 try these commands `cordova clean android` and after that
`cordova build android` . I hope that can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170902/discussion-between-riddhi-and-ivaro18).